# Efficient way to update columns in csv file in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm updating null line items in specific columns of a large csv file (~5GB) in the following way.

1. Convert csv file to Pandas Dataframe
2. If the required column in the dataframe has nulls, update it with specific values based on the values in a different column of the dataframe.    Eg : In the following code, I'm checking if 'center' column has null values, if yes, update it with '0070' for all line items that have account column value as 'DNA' or 'BBA'.

> ```
>    if df['center'].isnull().any().any() == True:
>       df.loc[df.account.str.startswith('DNA') | df.account.str.startswith('BBA'), 'center'] = "0070"
> ```

I'm obtaining the desired result by implementing the above, however since there are over 10 columns to check and update, this method is taking about 4-5 minutes to run on the entire dataset (~5GB). Is there a better way to improve code efficiency?

Comment: First, do you have enough RAM to comfortably load the entire file at once like this? If the slowdown is caused by swapping, you'll need to do some kind of iteration (whether standard Python row-by-row, or one of the HDF libraries' chunking import with passthrough, or…).

Comment: an iterative csv approach may be faster, but also look up `fillna`... it can do some of the things you want.

Comment: @abarnert - yes I have enough RAM to load the entire data at once. However, if the file size increases further chunking will be the approach I'll be looking into.

Comment: @CorleyBrigman - Thanks, I'll check if fillna can improve the performance.

Comment: If performance is your issue you may use `sed` for such. You can check this [sed tutorial on replacing emtpy values on csv](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-fill-all-empty-valued-cells-within-a-csv-file-with-sed-and-bash-shell). If you are not under linux or unix you can still get sed command from [`git`](https://git-scm.com/) program for example.